# docker on upstart on scaleway

Tags: docker, upstart, ubuntu-15.04

I have docker container based on ubuntu 12.04 and wish start it on [scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/imagehub/docker/) This instantApp run on ubuntu 15.04 with systemd. For my container I need upstart. I turn on upstart by this recommendation:

> Install the upstart-sysv package, which will remove ubuntu-standard and systemd-sysv (but should not remove anything else -- if it does, yell!), and run sudo update-initramfs -u. After that, grub's "Advanced options" menu will have a corresponding "Ubuntu, with Linux ... (systemd)" entry where you can do an one-time boot with systemd.

Now my server running with upstart:

```
# ps aux|grep upstart
root      1447  0.0  0.0   2632  1744 ?        S    13:44   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root      1598  0.0  0.0   2044   176 ?        S    13:44   0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root      2571  0.0  0.0   2032  1128 ?        S    13:44   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root     32408  0.0  0.0   3156  1472 pts/4    S+   14:27   0:00 grep --color=auto upstart
```

but docker not running:

```
# service docker status
 * Docker is managed via upstart, try using service docker status
# service docker start
 * Docker is managed via upstart, try using service docker start
```

How I can start docker as daemon?

Answer (score 0):

See answer for this Ask Ubuntu question - it's a workaround to get things running again until the Kernel bug is address:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/683462/docker-is-managed-via-upstart-try-using-service-docker